# Django rest framework serialization tutorial confused

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I don't get what following code does.I don't get from where `item[1][0]` comes to line 8. It is not defined.I don't get what next line does also.
btw I have a java background.

I get the idea of comprehensions so I get the seventh line.

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles`

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in get_all_styles()])
```

[Enter link description here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

Comment: it is a normal list comprehension, where they contract tuples from items in LEXERS

Comment: I don't get that.I'm not very much familiar with tuples either.can you please explain a bit further or can you pass a resource to lookup for.

Answer (score 1):

In your above code the `[item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]` returning a `list` of `tuple's` which is stored in variable `LEXERS`

Each element in `LEXERS` contains a `tuple` with `nested tuple`

```
>> LEXERS[1]
>> ('LessCss', ('less',), ('*.less',), ('text/x-less-css',))
```

On line `LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])`, 
Again with List comprehension it is iterating over the `list` of `tuple` and returning sorted `list` of `tuple` with some filtered data.

In a List Comprehension, while iterating over List `for item in LEXERS`, it treats each element from `LEXERS` as a `item` and performing operation over `item`(i.e. on List element).

Suppose that while iterating over list you are getting `item` with data

`('LessCss', ('less',), ('*.less',), ('text/x-less-css',))` it is accessing `item[1]` i.e. `('less',)` and `item[1][0]` means it is returning you `'less'` from 1st postion of tuple.

Hope this explanation will help you to understand the List Comprehension well !

Comment: Thank you very much but what does item[1][0] means

Comment: ('LessCss', ('less',), ('*.less',), ('text/x-less-css',)) it is accessing item[1] 
i.e. ('LessCss',) is this what you mean?

Comment: No,`item[1]` means `('less',)` , indices of tuple start from 0. `'LessCss'` can be accessible by `item[0]`

Comment: Yes.the thing is didn't catch this whole concept.but I'm asking what item[1][0] means.if item[1] means ('less',) then why there is [0] as well?

Comment: `('less' , ) ` is again tuple, and tuple elements can be accessible using index. So `item[0]` will return you `'less'` from the tuple

Comment: @kavindanehansana Will recommend you to go through the https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/ to get things clear

Comment: Ah now I got that thank you very much.
Can you also tell me what [(item[1][0], item[0]) means in this?